# Sequlize Postgres как посчитать количество связанных моделей?

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

Имееются таблица постов и категорий, связь многие ко многим. Связаны через промежуточную таблицу.

при запросе категорий выводятся связанные модели постов.

```
category: {
  id: 2,
  posts: [
   {id:1, title: 'test'}
  ]
}
```

как мне возвращать не сами посты, а только их количество?

```
Category.findAll({
      include: [
        {
          model: Post
        },
      ],
 })
```

Хочу на выходе получить

```
category: {
  id: 2,
  posts: 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Sequelize** не предназначен для сколько-нибудь сложных агрегаций, он больше о **CRUD** и подгрузке ассоциаций.
Вам нужно будет добавить подзапрос для этого в `attributes`.
Что-то типа такого:

```js
Category.findAll({
   attributes: {
     include: [[Sequelize.literal('(SELECT COUNT(*) from Posts p where p.category=category.id)'), 'posts']]
   }
 })
```